# selenium. Пройтись по элементам класса

Tags: java, selenium, list

Всем привет, хочу пройтись по странице и вытянуть текст с всех элементов в которых есть опредленный селектор.

```
public void validationCheck() {
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173bo-1DCAEoggI46AdICVgDaOkBiAEBmAEJuAEGyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBmAICqAID&sid=37df28c614f2a8906f7179fb8ae27553&tmpl=searchresults&ac_click_type=b&ac_position=0&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=1&checkin_year=2019&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2019&class_interval=1&dest_id=20088325&dest_type=city&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&iata=NYC&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src_elem=sb&ss=New%20York%2C%20New%20York%20State%2C%20USA&ss_raw=new&ssb=empty&order=popularity");
   List<WebElement> stringAdressCity = driver.findElements(
           By.cssSelector("#b_tt_holder_13"));

   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (WebElement webElement: stringAdressCity){
       String text = webElement.getText();
       list.add(text);
   }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Как бы не пытался, по xPath или по классу, но список stringAdressCity всегда имеет размер 0

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: 1. На той странице `#b_tt_holder_13` нет. Может надо авторизоваться? 2. `#b_tt_holder_13` - это не селектор класса, но селектор id. Не может быть нескольких элементов с одинаковым id - если такое происходит, берется первый. 3. Если элемент появляется не сразу, нужно `driver.wait(until.elementLocated({css: '#b_tt_holder_13'}), 500);`. PS. Java не знаю, с Selenium работал плотно

Comment: спасибо, помогло